# Pass a value from an object to another object in props

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

***Problem***

Hello to all,

Given the example code:

```
<Table
   data1={data}
   data2={columns}
/>
```

I've to pass `data.property` to `columns`,

I will get `data.property` after a successful call to a remote server, so initially data will be simply `null`.

I've the data inside columns displaying in this way:

```
const columns = [
  function() {data.property ? doThis : doThat },
  {object1},
  {object2},
  {object3},
  ....
]
```

***Consideration***

I cannot change the order or the dimension of the column, so I cannot merge the two objects and the const columns is in another file than the starting table.

We are using ReactTable.

***Why do I need the property of Data?***

I need it to do a check inside the function inside columns,
something like this:

`data.property.length ? DoThis : DoThat`

***My Tries***

I tried to merge the two object in a new one, but I messed up everything and  broke my table.

Comment: Can you share how you load the data and save it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the nature of your question, it appears you require to use onFetchData() to ensure *all* data is present *before* rendering the view.

An example of this type of usage is detailed within the [npm documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table#server-side-data) usage examples for the react-table project

This is the preferred method, I am familiar with the concept writing APIs in Express, where it is required that you use the async package along with a series of functions in order to ensure all data has been generated before the callback provides the data to your view being rendered.

Hopefully this fishing rod helps you in the right direction!

If this suggestion helps you, please do edit your question and share the solution you have written to tackle the issue so future viewers of this question can also benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but I can imagine that your code crashes due to either data or data.property being undefined, as it is still waiting for your asynchronous API call to finish.

In order to prevent this you could do the following:

```
( data && data.property && data.property.length ) ? DoThis : DoThat
```

Comment: No, it's not a problem linked to the call. The problem is that i need to use a property inside data in the column array ( that unluckly is in another file ). 

But man, thank you for your time :)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "...but I messed up everything and broke my table"?